# Yes(1)/No(0) output by applying multiple conditions in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I've been given Product Id against the order ids. Product Ids and Order Ids are provided in two different columns, adjacent to each other. The output expected out of the "Information Provided" table is that for all the order ids, which all product ids have been purchased. If purchased, then 1, otherwise it should be 0. The expected output is filled for A and B order ids. And this whole table should be automated.

Assume the Information Table is provided in the given format i.e., 2 columns for Product Ids and 2 columns for Order id.

I tried doing it through if and And function, but the output is 0 even for those which are actually present. Kindly help me out how to automate the binary output.

The tables are shown in the image file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This should be doable with COUNTIFS.

Comment: I tried doing via Countifs too. But the binary output is not coming.

Comment: Check if the result of Countifs is `>0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Binary COUNTIFS

For columns A, B, C, D and the results starting in cell G2:

```
=1*OR(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,G$1,$B$2:$B$11,$F2),COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$11,G$1,$D$2:$D$11,$F2))
```

[image]